# C# TCP client Socket talk to specific client

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to understand how I can interact with a specific client from server side.

```
private void StartListen()
        {
            //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
            tcpListener.Start();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
            int counter = 0;
            appStatus = 0;

            
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    counter++;
                    clientList.Add(client);
                    IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
                    //Updating status of connection
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from " + IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());
                    appStatus = 1;
                    Debug.WriteLine("list of clients"+clientList);
                    
                    th_outPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { outPutStream(client); });
                    th_outPutStream.Start();
                    th_inPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { inPutStream(client); });
                    th_inPutStream.Start();
                    th_checkConnection = new Thread(checkConnection);
                    th_checkConnection.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    {
                        Cleanup();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

From the above query, when a client connects to a server, i store it in the following list `List<TcpClient> clientList = new List<TcpClient>();` like so `clientList.Add(client);`

My question is, if in the example that I am connected to two clients, but want to send a message to only the second client, how can I do so?

Could I apply the following `thread-safe List<T>` to apply new clients to the list?

```
clientList.AsParallel().ForAll(item => clientList.Add(client));
```

Or would locking be required?

Comment: Um, you can get at the second client with `clientList[1]`... that gives you a `TcpClient`. I assume you know what to do from there?

Comment: I think you are confused because the way you print the client list (`Debug.WriteLine("list of clients"+clientList)`) returns the type of the list as a string instead of the data it contains. if you would serialize the list (`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientList)`) you'll see the data you are looking for

Comment: Be aware that a) using a non-thread-safe `List<T>` to keep a list of clients is doubtful at the best of times because almost always you'll end up accessing it from multiple threads and b) Thread-per-client doesn't tend to scale well. Here you're creating 3 for every connected client.

Comment: Why the extra block around `Cleanup()`? Is it a residue of older code?

Comment: @Fildor apologies, yes, that was a mistake from older code, ive made changes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have updated my answer with the threaded thread-safe List: clientList.AsParallel().ForAll(item => clientList.Add(client)); , is this a good approach?  What I dont understand what you are referring in relation to the thread-per-client (About creating 3 for every connected client).